# Read file to inmemory user manipulates info, then overwrites data back to same file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I have been reading posts trying to figure how to get this done. The title says it all. I am trying to take simple data from a text file and load in memory. Then let the user manipulate (add/delete) data in memory and have it added to an `List<Automobile>`. Then have it write what is in memory back to the same file by overwriting what is there. I have tried to use different parts of `MemoryStream()` and trying to use `StreamReader()`. I would get an error saying "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Exercise6_DealerVehicleInventory.Automobile'". When I would use `MemoryStream`, it would give me an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.StreamReader' to 'string'"

I am not that familiar with the .net framework and what all can be done with. What is the best way to go about doing what the Title of my post says? I have been reading for the past few days and not been able to figure this out. I am still very new to all that C# has to offer when writing applications.

PS: Where it says "Exercise6", this is not for school by any means. This is something that I was given and told to use online for help/answers if I had issues.

If there is another post that explains all of this, please point me to that post because I have not found a post/answer to what I am trying to get done.

Comment: I don't see any code so impossible to say anything

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I know I did not put any code. The reason I did not put any code is because everything that I had was just from what I was trying to take from different posts and put it together to do what I was wanting. It turned into one big mess and I knew that would get my question/post down voted. Sorry for there not being any code to go off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# makes this very easy for you.

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");

// change content here

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filename.txt", content);
```

To simplify things, you should add `using System.IO;` to the top of your file, and then you don't have to include `System.IO` in the body of the code.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for pointing this out me.

My next question is how do I get add what is read from the file to a `List<>` because I am trying to get it to where the user can also delete data from in memory.

Below, when I try and add that data back to the list, I get the following error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Exercise6_DealerVehicleInventory.Automobile'".

`                string content = File.ReadAllText(mydocpath + @"\Vehicle.txt");
                vehicle.Add(content);`

Obviously I am still missing something here that I should be catching.

Comment: @Daniel  you can read it into a list with `File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")`

Comment: and your error is probably because you're trying to put a `string` into a variable of the type `Automobile`

Comment: I have tried to add it to a list but that is not turning out that well for me. I am getting the following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Exercise6_DealerVehicleInventory.Automobile>".  This is is what my code looks like `List<Automobile> car = File.ReadAllLines(mydocpath + @"\Vehicle.txt");`. Hopefully you can help me figure this out because I thought I understood how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that:

1. Each line in the input file represents a single automobile.
2. You want to convert this list of strings to list of automobiles.

For simplicity, let's define the class Automobile as follows:

```
public class Automobile
{
    public string Name;

    //you can add more fields here.
}
```

Let's say that your input file "automobiles.txt" has the following lines:

**auto1**

**auto2**

**auto3**

Your program should be:

```
// read file content
string sFilePath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\automobiles.txt";
string[] aLines = File.ReadAllLines(sFilePath);

// initialize an empty list of automobiles
List<Automobile> lAutomobiles = new List<Automobile>();

// initialize a list of automobiles from file content
aLines.ToList().ForEach(line => lAutomobiles.Add(new Automobile { Name = line }));

// here, do whatever you want with the automobiles list
lAutomobiles.ForEach(auto => auto.Name += "_processed");

// write the processed data to the file
File.WriteAllLines(sFilePath, lAutomobiles.Select(auto => auto.Name));
```

After running this code, the lines in automobiles.txt are:

**auto1_processed**

**auto2_processed**

**auto3_processed**

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you want to add a string value to a list of Autmobile type.so you should create a complete Autombile class that has all info about autombiles, then when add to the list you can write something like that:

```
List<Autombile> auto = new List<Autombile>();
            auto.Add(new Autombile() { Name = "user's auto name", Model = "user's auto model" });
```

Comment: I have the `Automobile` class setup. I just did not put it in the code because I am having an issue trying to get what I have saved in the file wrote to inmemory that way vehicles can be deleted from the file. Then have it to where it will overwrite what has changed inmemory to the file. I am not sure if what I am saying/asking is make any sense because I am trying to make complete sense of it all still.